# Is there a way to make selecting a specific variable more efficient?

Tags: c++

So I'm writing a program that has 9 different mazes in it stored in 2d arrays all filled with hard coded values. When the player chooses the maze, I want to copy the hard coded values from the maze selected into the 2d array of the active maze. When I wrote it out I did it in the most straightforward way possible as you can see below. Then I wanted to maze it better as it seems... bloated. A switch case wouldn't reduce the amount of lines, so I wanted to make some way to immediately put the `int mazeSelection` variable into the variable name of the maze selected. But it seems you can't alter a variable name during runtime, nor use a string variable to represent the name of another variable. For example `string mazenumber = "maze" + tostring(mazeSelection);` then doing `mazenumber[11][11]` doesn't work, but that's the basic idea of what I want to do.

So the upshot is, is there a way to make this code more efficient?

```
    if(mazeSelection == 1)
        maze[11][11] = maze1[11][11];
    if(mazeSelection == 2)
        maze[11][11] = maze2[11][11];
    if(mazeSelection == 3)
        maze[11][11] = maze3[11][11];
    if(mazeSelection == 4)
        maze[11][11] = maze4[11][11];
    if(mazeSelection == 5)
        maze[11][11] = maze5[11][11];
    if(mazeSelection == 6)
        maze[11][11] = maze6[11][11];
    if(mazeSelection == 7)
        maze[11][11] = maze7[11][11];
    if(mazeSelection == 8)
        maze[11][11] = maze8[11][11];
    if(mazeSelection == 9)
        maze[11][11] = maze9[11][11];
```

Comment: use a std::vector and get the maze by "index" using the value of ***mazeSelection***

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ If `maze1` etc are arrays then they cannot be placed in a `std::vector`.

Comment: `maze[11][11] = maze1[11][11];` what to you think this code is doing? Do you think it is copying `maze1` to `maze`? If so then unfortunately you are mistaken.

Comment: Define a struct that represents a maze, store your nine mazes in a vector or array, and write `maze = mazes[mazeSelection];`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your question is lacking in detail, but lets assume you have this

```
int maze[11][11], maze1[11][11]; // etc
```

Then the first thing to say is that

```
maze[11][11] = maze1[11][11];
```

does not copy your maze. It's a very common beginner misunderstanding that you can refer to a whole array this way, but `maze1[11][11]` just refers to one element of the maze at coordinates (11,11) not to the whole maze. And worse since the size of the array is 11 by 11, that element doesn't actually exist, so the code is just an error. There is (surprisingly) no simple way to copy an array in C++.

The simplest suggestion (thanks to @molbdnilo) is to put your maze inside a struct.

```
struct Maze
{
    int tiles[11][11];
};

Maze maze, maze1; // etc
```

Now structs can be copied in the usual way, so

```
maze = maze1;
```

is legal code and does copy the maze.

Then you can go further and make an array of mazes, and write this simple code

```
Maze selected_maze, all_mazes[10];

selected_maze = all_mazes[mazeSelection];
```

Comment: So as you probably noticed, I don't have too much experience with coding. Now I'm just embarrassed because I did know that you can't copy an array like that, but I completely forgot. At the same time, I appreciate your alternate solution, as it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way for your case is to store needed to choose values in `vector` and then just index that vector. I.e. instead of writing

```
if (x == 0)
    y = z0;
else if (x == 1)
    y = z1;
else if (x == 2)
    y = z2;
```

you do

```
static vector<ValueT> values = {z0, z1, z2, ValueT()/*no answer for 3*/, z4, z5};
if (x < values.size())
    y = values[x];
else
    y = ValueT(); // No value found!
```

Note that above solution works good if keys to check (inside if condition) cover densely whole vector's range `[0;size)`, if some values are absent you may store in corresponding vector's slots special values signifying that there is no answer.

If keys-space is to sparse then there will be too many no-value elements in vector and this solution may be to memory-wasteful, then next other solutions will do. But this vector-solution is the fastest regarding speed of getting right value by given key.

In more difficult cases, when you need to have arbitrary expression inside if condition or when you need to run arbitrary code in if body, then you need to use more advanced solutions like those that I've just coded into code below (I've coded all cases in growing complexity order). All these solutions are implementing fastest way to make if/then choice.

I'll explain code a bit.

When if condition just checks for equality to number in range [0;size) and result is just a value then we use `vector`. vector's values can be plain objects to return, or functional objects to be run (in case of complex handlers that are inside if-body). This choice works in constant `O(1)` time, i.e. very fast (see [Time Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)).

If keys to compare to are sparse (e.g. numbers 10, 20, 30, 40) then we use `unordered_map` or `map`, map can be used for any keys that are orderable (for map) or support equality and hashable (for unordered_map). This solution works in `O(1)` time for `unordered_map`, i.e. very fast (but constant may be not very small), use unordered_map if you have dozens of if-cases. For `map` it works in `O(log(N))` time (N is number of handlers/if-bodies), so is also very fast, use it for cases below dozen. `map` is faster than `unordered_map` for small number of cases.

For the most complex case when if-conditions are complex expressions and if-bodies are also complex code-blocks, i.e. when we have func-func mapping, can be also solved fast in logarithmic time (`O(log(N))`) but only for the case if all if-cases can be ordered (sorted) in such a way that for each current if-case we can definitely tell if the correct matching case probably (if exists at all) lies in handlers to the left from current (flag `-1`) or that current case is matching one (flag `0`) or that correct matching case probably (if exists at all) lies in handlers to the right from current. In other words all handlers can be ordered in one definite way for all possible input arguments (of if-condition expression-func). In this case we just do a logarithmic-time [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) using [std::lower_bound(...)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound).

So all recommendations are:

1. If keys are non-negative integers (or keys can be mapped to such integers via some simple function) and if this integers space is not too sparse (otherwise vector-solution is memory-wasteful) then use `std::vector` for mapping. Fetching from vector by index is `O(1)` time with small constant time (several CPU instructions), i.e. very fast.
2. If there are very many keys (more than hundreds) and keys are equality-comparable and [hash-able](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) then use `std::unordered_map`. Fetching time by key is `O(1)` for unordered time, but with not-so-small constant time (hundred of CPU instructions), i.e. also very fast and fetch time doesn't grow with number of map elements.
3. If keys are not too many (below hundred) and keys are [fully-orderable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) (i.e. can be sorted) then use `std::map`. It has `O(log(N))` time with small constant, i.e. also very fast.
4. If there are no keys, i.e. if-conditions are complex expressions and there are many (more than dozen) of if cases then use `std::vector` of sorted pairs of functions representing a pair of `(if_condition_code_matcher, if_body_code)`. Searching matching cases would need `O(log(N))` number of if-condition-code evaluations, i.e. also very fast.
5. If there are very few (below 5-6) if-cases or if you don't need speed or when if-cases-handlers can't be sorted regarding all arguments or rules 1-5 don't apply or you simply don't want any complex solutions then use just plain set of ifs.
6. Rules 1-5 are all about different ways of fast finding matching if-case. Regarding values - all structures above can store any type of value. So:

   - Store regular objects as structure's values (`int`, `string`, or any class object) if your if-cases where just returning some data without any code-computation, like in your case. Just return this value after obtaining structure's slot by key.
   - Store functions as structure's values if your if-bodies contains complex code. After fetching by key just run this function-value as a handler.
7. Also in case of keys being integers (or map-able to them) like in case 1 you can also use old-good [switch-case](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch). Clever compilers optimize code in such a way that they use only [goto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto) commands for jumping to matching if-body. But for this case you need to have all cases within switch being ordered, and also all values for range `[0;size)` should be covered in switch's cases. But such optimization is not guaranteed, compiler still may do regular sequential if-condition-trying. Hence `vector` solution is the only guaranteed optimization.

Code below can also be [run online here](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64022609#main.cpp).

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define ASSERT_MSG(cond, msg) { if (!(cond)) throw runtime_error("Failed assertion [" #cond "]! Msg: " + string(msg)); }

typedef string ValT;

// Makes choice in fixed O(1) time.
// Suitable only for having possible mapping for all keys in range [0;size).
ValT const & HandleValToValVec(size_t i) {
    static std::vector<ValT> handlers = {"zero", "one", "two", "three"};
    
    if (i < handlers.size()) {
        ValT const & val = handlers[i];
        cout << "Key " << i << " was mapped to \"" << val << "\"" << endl;
        return val;
    } else {
        cout << "Key " << i << " has no mapping!" << endl;
        static ValT null_val;
        return null_val;
    }
}

typedef size_t KeyT;

// Makes choice in fixed O(1) time.
// Suitable for any comparable keys or if keys space is sparse (not covering range [0;size)).
ValT const & HandleValToValMap(KeyT const & key) {
    static std::unordered_map<KeyT, ValT> handlers = {{10, "ten"}, {20, "twenty"}};
    
    auto it = handlers.find(key);
    if (it == handlers.end()) {
        cout << "Key " << key << " has no mapping!" << endl;
        static ValT null_val;
        return null_val;
    } else {
        cout << "Key " << key << " was mapped to \"" << it->second << "\"" << endl;
        return it->second;
    }
}

// Makes choice in fixed O(1) time.
void HandleValToFunc(KeyT const & key) {
    // Handlers containing any arbitrary code, "static" here is important to re-create array only once.
    static std::unordered_map< KeyT, function<void()> > handlers = {
        {KeyT(10), [&](){
            cout << "Chosen Key 10" << endl;
        }},
        {KeyT(15), [&](){
            cout << "Chosen Key 15" << endl;
        }},
    };
    
    auto it = handlers.find(key);
    if (it == handlers.end())
        cout << "No Handler for Key " << key << endl;
    else
        it->second();
}

typedef string ArgT;

// Makes choice in logarithmic O(log(N)) time, where N is number of handlers.
void HandleFuncToFunc(ArgT const & arg0) {
    // Handlers containing any arbitrary code, "static" here is important to re-create array only once.
    // First function in handlers's pair should return -1 if matching handler probably lies to the left,
    // 0 if this handler is matching, 1 if probably lies to the right.
    static std::vector< pair< function<int(ArgT const &)>, function<void()> > > handlers = {
        {[](ArgT const & arg0)->int{
            return arg0.size() < 3 ? -1 : arg0.size() < 5 ? 0 : 1;
        }, [&](){
            cout << "Chosen String with len within range [3;5)." << endl;
        }},
        {[](ArgT const & arg0)->int{
            return arg0.size() < 6 ? -1 : arg0.size() < 8 ? 0 : 1;
        }, [&](){
            cout << "Chosen String with len within range [6;8)." << endl;
        }},
    };
    
    auto it = std::lower_bound(handlers.begin(), handlers.end(), arg0, [](auto const & handler, ArgT const & arg0) {
        return handler.first(arg0) > 0;
    });

    if (it == handlers.end() || it->first(arg0) != 0)
        cout << "No Handler for String \"" << arg0 << "\"" << endl;
    else
        it->second();
}

int main() {
    try {
        HandleValToValVec(0); HandleValToValVec(3); HandleValToValVec(5);
        HandleValToValMap(10); HandleValToValMap(20); HandleValToValMap(30);
        HandleValToFunc(10); HandleValToFunc(15); HandleValToFunc(20);
        HandleFuncToFunc("ab"); HandleFuncToFunc("abcd"); HandleFuncToFunc("abcde"); HandleFuncToFunc("abcdef"); HandleFuncToFunc("abcdefgh");
        return 0;
    } catch (exception const & ex) {
        cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```